# SQL Server : Insert Multiple Duplicate Records into Child table from Parent table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert Multiple rows into table **ProductImages** from table **Products** based upon the criteria of each record from Products table gets inserted into 3 times in `ProductImages table`
the following is a `product table`

```
Sno | Productid 
 1  |    ABC
 2  |    XYZ
 3  |    PQR
```

I want ProductImages Table as

```
Sno | ProductId | ImageId 
 1  |    ABC    | ABC_Small
 2  |    ABC    | ABC_Big
 3  |    ABC    | ABC_Biggest
 4  |    XYZ    | XYZ_Small
 5  |    XYZ    | XYZ_Big
 6  |    XYZ    | XYZ_Biggest
```

Is it possible to get the mutiple records as above from parent table of relationship with Productid? Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Try and organise your question so that is easier to read

Comment: On a sidenote you might want to rethink your database model as it doesn't seem to be properly normalized given that you're storing the ProductId in several places, unless this is by design for performance reasons or such.

Comment: @Gayathri Does the ProductImages table contain an auto incrementing Id namely Sno?

Comment: Yes Sno is the Auto increment column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @Product table(Sno int, Productid char(3))
declare @ProductImages Table(Sno int identity(1,1), ProductId char(3), ImageId varchar(20))

insert @Product
values(1, 'ABC'),(2, 'XYZ'),(3, 'PQR')

insert @ProductImages (ProductId, ImageId)
select p.ProductId,p.ProductId+ '_' +a.plus from @Product p
cross apply 
(values ('Small'), ('Big'), ('Biggest')) a(plus)

select * from @ProductImages
```

EDIT for sql 2000

```
insert @Product values(1, 'ABC')
insert @Product values(2, 'XYZ')
insert @Product values(3, 'PQR')


insert @ProductImages (ProductId, ImageId)
select p.ProductId,p.ProductId+ '_' +a.plus from @Product p
join 
(select 'Small' plus
union all select 'Big'
union all select 'Biggest') a(plus)
on 1 = 1
```

Result:

```
Sno ProductId ImageId
1   ABC       ABC_Small
2   ABC       ABC_Big
3   ABC       ABC_Biggest
4   XYZ       XYZ_Small
5   XYZ       XYZ_Big
6   XYZ       XYZ_Biggest
7   PQR       PQR_Small
8   PQR       PQR_Big
9   PQR       PQR_Biggest
```

Comment: thanq. Is there any way to insert it as dynamically from products table and also i am getting (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values')..

Comment: @Gayathri you are running an older version than 2008 on mssql. I will rewrite the script so it also works on 2000

Comment: Ya its working on 2008 r2 and please give the script to take the values from products table dynamically

Comment: @Gayathri I am not sure what you mean by: take the values from products table dynamically

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
insert ProductImages (ProductId, ImageId)
select
    p.Productid,
    p.Productid+'_'+size
from Products p
cross join (
    Select size
    From (
       Values 
          ('Small'), 
          ('Big'),
          ('Biggest')
    ) s(size)
) sizes
```

Comment: same answer as mine, just without the tables and result

Comment: @t-clausen.dk `cross apply` looks better than `cross join`

Comment: @Gayathri fixed autoincrement field